# Modify style elements of '.searchable' generated searchbar

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view with the .searchable() modifier.  I want to change how the searchbar looks, such as the font and shape and background color.

It doesn't seem like there's any direct ways to go about this from what I've googled.  I expected there to be just modifiers for it, but it seems that isn't the case.

Comment: Maybe you can use a TextField for this scenario?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.